How to setup Docker configuration for running Selenium Chrome tests with JDK17 and Gradle?
I am trying to setup a simple, straight forward setup to run some UI automation tests on a Gitlab pipeline. I am using the following Dockerfile to generate the image:
# Use a base image with Selenium and Chrome
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

# Set environment variables for Selenium, Chromium, and Chromedriver versions
ENV JDK_VERSION=17
ENV GRADLE_VERSION=8.7
ENV SELENIUM_VERSION=4.19.1
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=114.0.5735.90
ENV LOG4J_VERSION=2.17.1
ENV JUNIT_VERSION=5.9.1
ENV MOCKITO_INLINE_VERSION=5.2.0
ENV MOCKITO_VERSION=5.11.0
ENV LOMBOK_VERSION=1.18.32

# Install OpenJDK 17
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-17-jdk \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

# Create directory for JAR files
RUN mkdir -p /home/gradle/libs/

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip" -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && unzip -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /usr/local/bin \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

# Download Gradle 8.7
RUN wget -q "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip" -O /tmp/gradle.zip \
    && unzip -o /tmp/gradle.zip -d /home/seluser \
    && rm /tmp/gradle.zip \
    && mv /home/seluser/gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION /home/seluser/gradle

# Set Gradle home environment variable
ENV GRADLE_HOME /home/seluser/gradle

# Update PATH to include Gradle bin directory
ENV PATH $PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin

# Download Selenium JAR
RUN wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/$SELENIUM_VERSION/selenium-java-$SELENIUM_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/selenium-java.jar

# Download Log4j JARs
RUN wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/$LOG4J_VERSION/log4j-api-$LOG4J_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/log4j-api.jar && \
    wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/$LOG4J_VERSION/log4j-core-$LOG4J_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/log4j-core.jar

# Download JUnit JARs
RUN wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/$JUNIT_VERSION/junit-jupiter-$JUNIT_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/junit-jupiter.jar

# Download Mockito JARs
RUN wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-inline/$MOCKITO_INLINE_VERSION/mockito-inline-$MOCKITO_INLINE_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/mockito-inline.jar && \
    wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/$MOCKITO_VERSION/mockito-junit-jupiter-$MOCKITO_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/mockito-junit-jupiter.jar

# Download Lombok JARs
RUN wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/$LOMBOK_VERSION/lombok-$LOMBOK_VERSION.jar" -O /home/gradle/libs/lombok.jar

# Switch to the user seluser
USER seluser

# Command to run (optional)
CMD ["bash"]


I have built the above Dockerfile and all the dependencies and packages are installed correctly.
As part of my unit tests, I have some Mockito tests to verify Chrome is runnable (in headless mode) inside the image. Here is my ChromeDriverManager:
package drivers.managers;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import drivers.DriverManager;
import drivers.Environment;

@Log4j2
public class ChromeDriverManager extends DriverManager {

    @Setter
    private Environment driverEnvironment;
    @Getter
    private WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * Generate a new Driver Manager on the supplied Environment.
     *
     * @param environment Environment to use (eg, LOCAL, DOCKER, etc.)
     */
    public ChromeDriverManager(final Environment environment) {
        driverEnvironment = environment;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the Chrome Selenium WebDriver. Should be called from within your Test setup.
     */
    public void initDriver() {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        log.debug("Initializing driver...");

        // Kill the previous WebDriver, if any
        closeDriver();

        switch (driverEnvironment) {
            case LOCAL -> {
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            }
            case DOCKER -> {
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1600,1200");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            }
            default -> throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    String.format("Environment \"%s\" is not yet implemented.", driverEnvironment));
        }
        log.debug(String.format("Generated new web driver object. driver=%s timeMs=%d", driver,
                (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)));
    }

    /**
     * Close the WebDriver instance.
     */
    public void closeDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            log.debug("Quitting driver instance: {}", driver);
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}


Here is my unit tests:
package drivers.managers;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException;

import drivers.Environment;

public class ChromeDriverManagerTest {

    @Mock
    private WebDriverFactory webDriverFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    private ChromeDriverManager chromeDriverManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    private void testInitDriver(final Environment environment) {
        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        when(webDriverFactory.createChromeDriver(chromeOptions)).thenReturn(mock(ChromeDriver.class));
        chromeDriverManager.setDriverEnvironment(environment);
        chromeDriverManager.initDriver();

        assertTrue(isBrowserAlive());
        chromeDriverManager.closeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    void testInitDriverDocker() {
        testInitDriver(Environment.DOCKER);
    }

    @Test
    void testInitDriverUnsupportedEnvironment() {
        chromeDriverManager = new ChromeDriverManager(Environment.UNSUPPORTED);

        // When trying to initialize driver with unsupported environment, UnsupportedOperationException should be thrown
        assertThrows(UnsupportedOperationException.class, chromeDriverManager::initDriver);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the browser is alive by navigating to google.com.
     * @return - True of False
     */
    private boolean isBrowserAlive() {
        try {
            chromeDriverManager.getDriver().navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
            return true;
        }
        catch (final UnreachableBrowserException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    interface WebDriverFactory {
        WebDriver createChromeDriver(ChromeOptions options);
    }
}


I build my repo using ./gradlew build or gradle build (in the image).
My issue is everything works as expected on my laptop (Macbook) while I get the following error inside the docker image:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Java compiler is not available. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jre-amd64 contains a valid JDK installation.

I feel I am missing something in the Docker installation or I am not using the right combination for my Selenium, Chrome, JDK17, Gradle, Mockito, etc. setup. Can someone help me (or guide) to the right combination of dependencies for setting this up?
